# Converts character array to CStringArray in c++

Tags: c++, mfc

I have character array like

`char *a[]={"hi","hello","how are you"};`

I want to convert it into `CStringArray`

How can I do this?

Comment: Post what you have tried?

Comment: Avoid any CContainer of MFC and use std::containers.

Comment: It should be `const char *a[]`

Comment: @AnoopLL I know the way to convert character array to CString but I want to convert it into CStringArray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char *a[] = { "hi","hello","how are you" };
CStringArray array;

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]); i++)
{
    array.Add(a[i]);
}
```

`sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])` is the number of string literals in the `a` array, that is 3.

Comment: It gives me error saying `INT_PTR CStringArray::Add(LPCTSTR)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char *' to 'LPCTSTR'

Comment: @MahekShah strange, it compiles here. What is your OS, compiler, IDE etc. ?

Comment: M using visual studio on windows 7.

Comment: Change `char *a[] = { "hi","hello","how are you" };` to `TCHAR *a[] = { _T("hi"), _T("hello"), _T("how are you") };` If it compiles, then its because you are compiling your program for unicode.

Comment: If you don't want to use unicode, right click on the project name in the solution explorer, choose Properties, select General and under "Character set" choose "Use Multi-Byte Character Set". Then the version in my answer should compile.

Comment: Yes It is now running.   Thanks @michael

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105657/discussion-between-mahek-shah-and-michael-walz).

Comment: @MichaelWalz - the recent versions of MFC don't support multi-byte character set.

Comment: @VladFeinstein, yes they do, you must download an addon from Microsoft. The URL is specified in the error message displayed by VS when you try to compile an MBCS program without the addon installed. They added this soon after VS2012 came out, because there is still tons of legacy code out there which is being maintained.

Comment: Proposing to use MBCS for **new** code is questionable. Just because Microsoft released a package supporting MBCS for MFC does not mean, one should be using it without a striking reason. The array should be declared constant as well: `const char* const a[] ...`.